# How to use GIMP to change the icon's color?

Tags: gimp

[image]

I want to change the red color #c0283d to #34a2fb while keep the shadow using GIMP.

Answer (score 1):

for this icon, `pdb.gimp_colorize(drawable, hue, saturation, lightness)` should work. you can look it up in gimp's procedure browser.